# Intermittent type error when trying to split an array into an array of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So I have an array of "phrases" for a game show app project. I'm trying to generate a random number, to select a phrase within that array, then split the phrases characters.

When I return it with .split(), and call the function in the console, I get a type error, but it seems intermittent, if I call it several times, sometimes it works, others it throws a type error.

What seems to be the issue?

```
    const phrases = [
    'JavaScript is the best programming language',
    'I love CSS',
    'Check out Peer Reviews',
    'Stack Overflow',
    'This is in the phrases array'
    ];

    const getRandomPhraseAsArray = arr => {
    const randomNumber = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) +1];
    return randomNumber.split("");    
    };
```

```
app.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at getRandomPhraseAsArray (app.js:22)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: it's because of the `+1` as @CodeManiac mentioned.

With `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) +1`, your random value can return 1, which will give the array length. This is already too large, then you're additionally adding 1 to it.

Comment: The error is intermittent because of the randomisation. When the index evaluates to `array.length`, which it will 1 time in 5, your program throws an error. Remove the `+1` and it will work correctly. (Your program also never selects the first element of the array.)

Comment: @StevenStark `Math.random` can never result in 1 (it's a random number in the interval [0,1), so can be 0 but not 1). Remove the `+1` and this code will work perfectly.

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry my mistake about random, you're right.

Comment: Oh wow that makes so much sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to add 1 to your `Math.Random()` This function gives a value between 0 to 1 and after you multiply whatever value it gives with the array length you are good to go *but* when you add `+1` to it, It sometimes exceeds the array length. the proper fix should be:

```
  const phrases = [
    'JavaScript is the best programming language',
    'I love CSS',
    'Check out Peer Reviews',
    'Stack Overflow',
    'This is in the phrases array'
    ];

    const getRandomPhraseAsArray = arr => {
   //removed the +1 here
    const randomNumber = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    return randomNumber.split("");    
    };
```

Hope this helps!